# Do I need a black stroke when saving white artwork for it to be able to print?

Tags: vector, print-design, screen-printing

[image]

White vector graphic with black stroke, do I need this for printing? Otherwise artwork is white and artboard is white, any other ways to do this?

This artwork will be silk screened on a T-Shirt using white ink.

How does one design with white when you can't see it in the application?

Comment: Ensure the white is white and not "paper" then print on colored paper if that's what you want. Otherwise, I too am unclear what you're asking.

Comment: welcome to the site.  At this time its unclear what you're asking and it looks like you were trying to add an image or link to your question.  Please make an [edit] to your question with more detail on what you're trying to do and we can try to help you.

Comment: Fill your artwork with black, while you're working on it, so you can see what you're doing.  When you have your design complete, change it back to white.  If you are printing on white paper though, this obviously won't work...

Comment: How can anyone answer this effectively?? Are you printing white ink?? What are you printing on?

Comment: Its a vector graphic to be printed on a tshirt. I need it to be printed white but without a stroke when i save as a pdf the file looks blank.

Comment: If you're screen printing the image, you will have the image black, no stroke. This is if you're using film to put on a screen. How are you planning on putting the image onto the shirt?

Comment: The file looks blank because your background is white. Is your T-shirt white? If not, then not a big deal. But in general, the screen printer wants a black plate to create their screen. So your design can be solid black if you want...just tell them to use white ink. (But, in general: Ask your printer)

Answer (score 2):

This would be a question for the printer.  Depending on how the document needs to be setup they may require a certain amount of bleed for the black stroke.  This bleed is usually cut off when they trim to the final size. I would suggest asking your printer what they prefer and what their protocol is for strokes on the edges.

---

After edit:

If this is to be screen printed it isn't going to matter what color you make it as long as it's a solid color with a quality vector object so I would get rid of the stroke and design in black.  Again, consult with the printer.  The printer may want you to deliver it in a certain manner.  If the graphic is to be printed as white it isn't going to matter to the printer as long as the vector's are solid because the plate maker will print it as a solid color.  Still you should be consulting the printer.

For you to get a better idea of what is going on here is a video you should watch on how it is done with vinyl: [Make Screen Printing Plate by 24in Cutting Plotter Sign Vinyl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1GG-Fcywzg).  Personally I would have weeded the vinyl before masking it and applying it to the screen but this should help you understand what is going on.

Overview of the video:

- Vinyl printed out on plotter
- Ideally it should we weeded before masking but they mask the decal
- Apply the decal to the screen
- Squeegee to get out all air bubbles
- transfer to press
- coat screen
- apply to shirt

Another method instead of vinyl is some people will use emulsion and burn it to the screen.  Either way that is up to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

Artwork, as in your sample image, should be 100% black, no stroke.

You make things black which are supposed to print. Black is transferred to film, then a plate and the ink is applied where the black image was... doesn't matter what color of ink is used, white, green, purple, bleen.

Think of it like a rubber stamp... the rubber part is black.. but you can dip that black rubber into red ink then press it onto something to get a red impression. The color of the artwork for 1 color printing is always black (or tints of black if you don't want a solid color).